# Assign a field value to another field for all data in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

When I was making bulk modifications to my data, this problem occurred.

```
User.find().then((r) => {
        console.log(r)
        r.forEach((elem) => {
            User.update(
                {
                    _id: elem._id
                },
                {
                    "$set": {
                        "openapi": elem.unionid
                    }
                }
            );
        })
    });
```

I used the above method, but the data did not change. PS: I have checked the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way is to use update with pipeline:

```
User.updateMany(
  {},
  [{$set: {openapi: "$unionid"}}]
)
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KhKdWO7UG-j)

Comment: That's cool, thank you. This answer is really helpful. Wish you have a nice day.